# I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS but getting some error

Tags: system-installation

Since few days I was trying to live boot Ubuntu so that I can install it into my laptop but unfortunately I am getting one error and from myself now I am not able to solve this. I am including the screen short of the error. Because I am new to Ubuntu so don't want to messup my question.

[image]

Comment: The actual error message has already scrolled off the screen -- it should have been before the register dump. What Ubuntu specifically? On what kind of computer (CPU, memory, make, model, BIOS/EFI, disk/SSD)?

Comment: This is the only msg  i can see. I can't scroll the page.<br> Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: I am using HP follio 9470m, 4gb ram, 500 gb hdd and intel i5 processor

Comment: [It should work](http://www.linlap.com/hp_elitebook_folio_9470m), except that some users are complaining that trying to install `grub` on the MSATA drive causes grief.

Comment: I didn't did anything I can install any version of windows, I can run trail. Previously I had installed Ubuntu without any problem, but I don't know why I am getting this error this time.

Comment: I have also deleted all partition and formatted entire hdd to solve this problem but still getting same error

Comment: This same usb drive is working well in other desktops and laptops, but only in my laptop it is showing error

Comment: I have no more advice to give. Let's hope somebody else has an idea.

Comment: Okay, thanks that you tried to help me, I hope someone will come very soon to help me

Comment: TPM is the Trusted Platform Module... has to do with encryption and security. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module. Maybe if you can disable TPM or any passwords that you have set?

Comment: I have not set any password infact everything was working fine. I am facing this problem since I tried to install Arch Linux, since then I am facing this problem.

Comment: I am very disappointed with the help I get here, I read a lot about the linux community for their help, but still no one helped me. :(

Comment: Did you disable the TPM? (And don't complain you haven't received any help yet: it's only been 10 hours since you posted your question and 31 people have had a look and 2 have tried to help you already.  Give it at least 24h as this is a global community. ) Also: [edit] your post and post any of the relevant comments into your question itself so the experienced users don't have to read all of the comments but can instead focus on the question itself instead of the comments.

Comment: I have not disabled TPM also i am not sure how to enable or disable it.